# Exclude object from queryset if any of it's many to many related objects has a given property value

Tags: django, django-orm

let's say I have a models like this:

```py
class Bar(Model):
  value = IntegerField()

class Foo(Model):
  bars = ManyToManyField(Bar)
```

Now, how do I get a queryset of Foo objects, excluding the ones, which have any of `bars` object with value of `0`?

Corresponding Python code would be like this:

```py
foos_ids_to_exclude = []
for foo in Foo.objects.all():
  for bar in foo.bars.all():
    if bar.value == 0:
      foos_ids_to_exclude.append(foo.id)
      break

resulting_queryset = Foo.objects.exclude(id__in=foos_ids_to_exclude)
```

But how do I do this on DjangoORM level? It's even possible?

I want to do this without evaluating the queryset if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with [**`.exclude(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) with:

```
Foo.objects.exclude(bars__value=0)
```

Note that `Foo`s that do not have any related `Bar` will still be in the queryset.